# array data compression that is holding 13268 bits(1.66kBytes)

Tags: lossless-compression

i.e array is having 100*125 bits of data for each aircraft+8 ascii messages each of 12 characters 
what compression technique should i apply to such data

Answer (score 0):

Depends mostly on what those 12500 bits look like, since that's the biggest part of your data.  If there aren't any real patterns in it, or if they aren't byte-sized or word-sized patterns, "compressing" it may actually make it *bigger*, since almost every compression algorithm will add a small amount of extra data just to make decompression possible.

Comment: well , thanks for replying 
bits are arranged into frame in a pattern e.g as lat-long-track id-speed etc..
plz suggest some good compression programme for such small data as this